# Cross reference xml files that have been loaded into a list as strings, break them apart and retrieve specific data from them

Tags: xml, vb.net, procedural

```
Main Form Code: https://pastebin.com/31gjpzm6 < Outdated
Blueprint Input Code W/ Mods: https://pastebin.com/KsF2vAWw < Outdated
```

Mods from "%AppData%\Roaming\SpaceEngineers\Mods" are extracted to 
"C:\SETools\unpacked_mods\" into a folder named by an integer which is equal to the number that it was extracted so the first mod is 0 second is 1 and so on.

A typical mod will have its main data file like so "C:\SETools\unpacked_mods\0\data\CubeBlocks.sbc" and the internal data is in XML as well.

```
CubeBlocks.sbc Mod Info File: https://pastebin.com/UhhGtEhN
```

So what i want to do is cross-reference the modded subtype id in the blueprint file with the one in all the mod files and check if they match and if they do then grab their Icon which is in DDS format and send it to a picturebox which has already been generated in the Form1 code above. And i want to do this by retrieving the  path to a string.

```
Screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/3bIfN
```

So my question is how do i go about writing a function to do this without writing an IF function for each mod, basically i want to make a list of vanilla blocktypes and do like an if blockname is = to any item in the list of vanilla blocks then run the check for mods function.

What ive got so far:

```
Public Sub LoadModDefinitions()
    Dim modpath As String = "C:\SETools\unpacked_mods\"

    For Each entry In Directory.GetFiles(modpath, "CubeBlocks.sbc") 'For each zipfilename in the given directory extract them to the given folder
        Dim filereader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(modpath)
        For Each block In entry
            ModdedCubeblockDefinitions.Add(filereader.ReadToEnd(modpath))
        Next block
    Next
End Sub
```

^ This loads all the modded block information into a list.

And the function in question is the one below how can i search each block of data in the list of modded block data, find out which one contains the input "subtypesearch" & return a specific chunk of that files contents which is a file path between "" and "/icon"

```
Public Function SearchModdedCubeDefinitions(subtypesearch As String) 'WIP WIP WIP WIP WIP WIP
    Dim BlockToSearch As String = subtypesearch

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

And the automatic extracting of the mods files

```
'Check if program has been ran before and extract all mods if it hasnt
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Try
        'Check if the program directory exists & if not then create it
        If Not Directory.Exists("C:\SETools") Then
            Try
                Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\SETools")
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End If
        'Check if the mod extraction directory exists in the C drive & if not then create it
        If Not Directory.Exists("C:\SETools\unpacked_mods") Then
            Try
                Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\SETools\unpacked_mods")
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End If
        'Check if the file that determins whether or not the program has been run before exists or not & if not then create it
        If Not File.Exists("C:\SETools\Activated.txt") Then
            Try
                File.CreateText("C:\SETools\Activated.txt")
                'Unpack all mods
                unpackAll(sepath, extractto)
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Currently it seems that all the files are being read into the string list with no issue but i have no idea where to even start with the search function. I have a function written already for something i was doing before to search textboxes and was thinking of trying to implement it here but I'm still going to be concerned on how to return the text between the icon tags, i was thinking maybe using regex string splitting but I'm not quite sure any pointers?

Current Search Function

```
Private Function FindWords(ByVal TextSearched As String, ByVal Paragraph As String) As Integer
    Dim location As Integer = 0
    Dim occurances As Integer = 0
    Do
        location = TextSearched.IndexOf(Paragraph, location)
        If location <> -1 Then
            occurances += 1
            location += Paragraph.Length
        End If
    Loop Until location = -1
    Return occurances
End Function
```

Comment: Anyone?????????

Comment: errr its painful to not have an answer yet it just makes it more intriguing for me to be the first to do it :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using serialization to solve the problem

XMLCleaner.vb

```
Public Class XMLCleaner
    Public Function CleanXML(inputfile As String)
        Dim originalxml As String = inputfile
        Dim outputxml As String = Nothing

        'only keep requested xml lines and remove xsi:type from <definition> element
        For Each line In originalxml.Split(vbNewLine)
            If line.ToString().Contains("<?xml") Then
                outputxml += line.ToString() + vbNewLine
            ElseIf line.ToString().Contains("<Definitions xmlns:xsi") Then
                outputxml += line.ToString() + vbNewLine
            ElseIf line.ToString().Contains("<CubeBlocks>") Then
                outputxml += line.ToString() + vbNewLine
            ElseIf line.ToString().Contains("<Definition xsi:type") Then
                outputxml += "<Definition>" + vbNewLine
            ElseIf line.ToString().Contains("<Definition>") Then
                outputxml += line.ToString() + vbNewLine
            ElseIf line.ToString().Contains("<Id>") Then
                outputxml += line.ToString() + vbNewLine
            ElseIf line.ToString().Contains("</Id>") Then
                outputxml += line.ToString() + vbNewLine
            ElseIf line.ToString().Contains("<TypeId>") Then
                outputxml += line.ToString() + vbNewLine
            ElseIf line.ToString().Contains("<SubtypeId>") Then
                outputxml += line.ToString() + vbNewLine
            ElseIf line.ToString().Contains("<DisplayName>") Then
                outputxml += line.ToString() + vbNewLine
            ElseIf line.ToString().Contains("<Icon>") Then
                outputxml += line.ToString() + vbNewLine
            ElseIf line.ToString().Contains("<CubeSize>") Then
                outputxml += line.ToString() + vbNewLine
            ElseIf line.ToString().Contains("<BlockPairName>") Then
                outputxml += line.ToString() + vbNewLine
            ElseIf line.ToString().Contains("<BuildTimeSeconds>") Then
                outputxml += line.ToString() + vbNewLine
            ElseIf line.ToString().Contains("<Components>") Then
                outputxml += line.ToString() + vbNewLine
            ElseIf line.ToString().Contains("<Component Subtype") Then
                outputxml += line.ToString() + vbNewLine
            ElseIf line.ToString().Contains("</Components>") Then
                outputxml += line.ToString() + vbNewLine
            ElseIf line.ToString().Contains("</Definition>") Then
                outputxml += line.ToString() + vbNewLine
            ElseIf line.ToString().Contains("</CubeBlocks>") Then
                outputxml += line.ToString() + vbNewLine
            ElseIf line.ToString().Contains("</Definitions>") Then
                outputxml += line.ToString() + vbNewLine
            End If
        Next

        Return outputxml
    End Function
End Class
```

This method extracts only the wanted data from the cubeblocks file of every mod to make it serializable by the universal cubeblocks deserializer I made to answer another question I had.

CubeBlocksSerializer.vb

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On

Imports System.Xml.Serialization

<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.7.3081.0"),
 System.SerializableAttribute(),
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(),
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True),
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute([Namespace]:="", IsNullable:=False)>
Partial Public Class Definitions
    Private cubeBlocksField() As DefinitionsDefinition
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Definition", IsNullable:=False)>
    Public Property CubeBlocks() As DefinitionsDefinition()
        Get
            Return Me.cubeBlocksField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.cubeBlocksField = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.7.3081.0"),
 System.SerializableAttribute(),
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(),
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True)>
Partial Public Class DefinitionsDefinition
    Private idField As DefinitionsDefinitionID
    Private displayNameField As String
    Private iconField As String
    Private cubeSizeField As String
    Private componentsField() As DefinitionsDefinitionComponent
    Private blockPairNameField As String
    Private buildTimeSecondsField As Integer

    Public Property Id() As DefinitionsDefinitionID
        Get
            Return Me.idField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.idField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property DisplayName() As String
        Get
            Return Me.displayNameField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.displayNameField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Icon() As String
        Get
            Return Me.iconField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.iconField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property CubeSize() As String
        Get
            Return Me.cubeSizeField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.cubeSizeField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Component", IsNullable:=False)>
    Public Property Components() As DefinitionsDefinitionComponent()
        Get
            Return Me.componentsField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.componentsField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property BlockPairName() As String
        Get
            Return Me.blockPairNameField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.blockPairNameField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property BuildTimeSeconds() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me.buildTimeSecondsField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.buildTimeSecondsField = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.7.3081.0"),
 System.SerializableAttribute(),
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(),
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True)>
Partial Public Class DefinitionsDefinitionID
    Private typeIdField As String
    Private subtypeIdField As String

    Public Property TypeId() As String
        Get
            Return Me.typeIdField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.typeIdField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property SubtypeId() As String
        Get
            Return Me.subtypeIdField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.subtypeIdField = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.7.3081.0"),
 System.SerializableAttribute(),
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(),
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True)>
Partial Public Class DefinitionsDefinitionComponent
    Private subtypeField As String
    Private countField As Integer
    Private countFieldSpecified As Boolean

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>
    Public Property Subtype() As String
        Get
            Return Me.subtypeField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.subtypeField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>
    Public Property Count() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me.countField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.countField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()>
    Public Property CountSpecified() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me.countFieldSpecified
        End Get
        Set
            Me.countFieldSpecified = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

This class deserializes the cubeblocks file to a dictionary of DefinitionsDefinition class see below.

Main.vb

```
Public ModBlockDefinitionDictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, DefinitionsDefinition)

Public Sub LoadModDefinitions()
        Dim modpath As String = My.Settings.SpaceEngineersWorkingDirectory
        Dim id As Integer = 0
        Dim Cleaner As New XMLCleaner()

        For Each folder In Directory.GetDirectories(modpath)
            Dim folder_complete As String = folder.ToString() + "\Data"

            For Each file In Directory.GetFiles(folder_complete, "CubeBlocks.sbc") 'For each zipfilename in the given directory extract them to the given folder
                Dim moddedxml As String = Cleaner.CleanXML(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file))
                Dim DefinitionData As New Definitions()
                Dim xmlSerializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(Definitions))

                Try
                    Dim streamread As New StringReader(moddedxml)
                    DefinitionData = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(streamread)
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try

                For Each BlockDefinition In DefinitionData.CubeBlocks()
                    Try
                        If Not ModBlockDefinitionDictionary(BlockDefinition.Id.SubtypeId.ToString()) Is Nothing Then
                            'Block already exists dont add it
                        Else
                            ModBlockDefinitionDictionary.Add(BlockDefinition.Id.SubtypeId.ToString(), BlockDefinition)
                        End If
                    Catch ex As Exception

                    End Try
                Next
            Next

            id += 1
        Next
    End Sub
```

Then for each mod block you want to check you can fetch that block from the ModBlockDefintionsDictonary using its subtype id as the key.